# Owl Carousel alt tag issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I modify Owl Carousel  plugin to include

> alt

tags on all images? Currently they show up blank like

```
<img src="/uploads/2014/11/2-min-1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

As i can't include alt tag i can't complete SEO functionality Please help.

Comment: Regretfully, it appears there are no `apply_filter` calls in the plugin's rendering of the HTML from the `wp_owl` shortcode. Therefore, there is no hook, no elegant way to add the `alt` attribute to the image tags. You might consider a different slider, asking the plugin author to extend the functionality of the plugin, or forking & extending the plugin yourself.

Comment: See here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-alt-tags-to-images/ the title should be added. Otherwise it could be a plugin/theme conflict.